# CSS Clip Path align circle to left side

Tags: css, clip-path

I want to make a gdpr consent floater that expands once on page load and on hover. I found that CSS `clip-path` might be a great solution.

On the default state, I want only to show a circle with the consent icon.

[image]

On the hover state, I want to show the circle and the text.

[image]

As you can see in the first image, the circle isn't perfect. Using `clip-path: circle();` would make a perfect circle, but it is centered by default. Adding any parameters makes things a guessing game. `clip-path: circle(19% at 13% 50%);` is approx. what I want, however it's neighter perfect nor do I think it's good practice. It would break with other translations of the word or when changing the font etc.

So, can I use clip path to make a perfect circle that is calculated by the height of the element                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          (therefore radius 50% of height) and that is aligned to the left of the element?

SCSS

```
.gdpr__floating_container {

  &__animate {
    animation: gdpr__floating_container ease-in-out 1500ms;
    @keyframes gdpr__floating_container {
      50% {
        clip-path: circle(100%);
      }
    }
  }

  clip-path: circle(19% at 13% 50%);
  transition: clip-path 750ms;

  &:hover {
    clip-path: circle(100%);
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="gdpr__floating_container rounded-pill bg-dark text-light" style="font-size: 1.2rem; cursor: pointer; position: fixed; display: flex; left: 1vw; bottom: 1vw; align-items: center;">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-primary" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">
      <svg class="icon">
         <use href="/fontawesome/sprites/solid.svg#cookie-bite"></use>
      </svg>
   </button>
   <span class="pr-4">Datenschutz</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question was: can `clip-path: circle()` be aligned left in a none squared rectangle.

**The answer is mostly no**, unless you align it manually with pixels. E.g.: `clip-path: circle(25px at 25px 50%);`.

Aligning at 0 creates a half circle, therefore it has to be positioned exactly at *1x radius* (25px in this example).

This works, however, only on fixed dimensioned objects. No luck for more dynamic boxes.

Answer (score 1):

> I think you should 'make grow' a parent element with the same
> `border-radius` and `background-color` on hover. It will do the same
> effect without moving your image.
>
> Anyways, it would be nice to check out your HTML code.

**EDIT:**

Checkout this Codepen,

https://codepen.io/filoscoder/pen/abpxRmg

Comment: I see your point and - in fact - this is what i tried before. However `clip-path` seemed so clean and promising. So, to your knowledge, aligning a clip path circle to the left is not possible or desirable at the moment? And to go with `overflow: hidden` and `width` expansion. Thanks for your input, it is very well appreciated. PS: Using px instead of percentages improves the problem slightly, yet not completely: `clip-path: circle(25px at 25px 50%);`

Comment: Glad to contribute. If I had a reproducible code I would give you more accurate help.
Please upload your update if you solve it!

Comment: I already added the html in the original post. It depends on bootstrap btw. Thanks

Comment: I tried to replicate & give some guide for your case on codepen, check the link on the answer!

Comment: Did you checked the codepen in my answer?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes, I checked it. Made something similar, you can see it at my website ptmr.io. Thanks, cheers!